# Как получить миллисекунды?

Tags: java

Как получить миллисекунды?

```
public static int getHours(int totalSeconds) {
        return totalSeconds / 3600;
    }

public static int getMinutes(int totalSeconds) {
        return (totalSeconds - 3600*getHours(totalSeconds)) / 60;
    }

public static int getSeconds(int totalSeconds) {
        return totalSeconds - 3600*getHours(totalSeconds) - 60*getMinutes(totalSeconds);
    }

public static int getMilliseconds(int totalSeconds) {
        return ???
    }
```

Comment: в данном случае - никак

Comment: Может кто-нибудь объяснит затею автора? Если он просто не знает сколько миллисекунд в секунде, то пусть знает - их там тыща. Таким образом ??? превращаются в return 1000 * totalSeconds.

Comment: @Sergey, как я понял - TimeSpan в секундах и надо получить составляющие: дни, часы, минуты, секунды, миллисекунды

Comment: return 1000 * totalSeconds

возвращает такое число
00:00:77.77000
мс дублируют секунды

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как миллисекунды, это часть от секунды, а параметр - **целое** число секунд, то данная функция может вернуть **только** - 0.

Comment: А если сделать переменную double вместо int?

Comment: Тогда берешь дробную часть и умножаешь на 1000

Comment: @klieve, по большому счету миллисекунды можно вообще не брать, а выводить просто секунды с дробной частью

Comment: слишком много кода переделывать мне так, легче сделать double для мс

Comment: @klieve, ну если передавать будешь все равно инт - не будет никакой разницы. он просто 0 вернет и все